# Show/hide buttons in "ion-nav-bar" with respect to view

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-view

I like to hide and show icons depending on view. Which I am not able to do because `ion-nav-bar` is being accessed only from `tabsCtrl`

Here is view Markup:

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
  <ion-nav-back-button> </ion-nav-back-button>
  <ion-nav-title>My App Title</ion-nav-title>
  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
    <button class="button icon ion-ios-information-outline" ng-click="openFaqModal()" ng-hide="showHideFAQ"></button>
    <button class="button icon ci-bookmark" ng-click="openBoookmarkModal()" ng-show="showHideBookmark"></button>
  </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

Here is controller:

```
// Tab Controller - *** This Work ***
.controller('TabCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $rootScope.showHideFAQ = true;
  $rootScope.showHideBookmark = true;
})

// Detail Controller - *** This do not work ***
.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $rootScope.showHideFAQ = true;
  $rootScope.showHideBookmark = true;
})
```

Here is Route:

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
.state('tab', {
  url: '/tab',
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: 'views/tabs.html',
  controller: 'TabCtrl'
})

.state('tab.detail', {
  url: '/resources/:resourcesId',
  views: {
    'tab-resources': {
      templateUrl: 'views/detail.html',
      controller: 'DetailCtrl'
    }
  }
})
```

I am not sure why it's working in "TabCtrl" but not in "DetailCtrl" as both the controller is loaded in one view. I have a doubt it's something to do with `scope`.

Comment: i think you miss to inject  **$rootScope** in both controller, and once you set value in **$rootScope** will remain same through whole app session.

Comment: @Naitik I tried that already but, as mentioned `TabCtrl` is available in all views, I cannot reset it back once it enters desired view.

Comment: then use **$localStorage** instead of **$rootScope**

Answer (score 0):

I am using `$ionicView.enter` and `$ionicView.leave` to solve my issue:

```
// Detail Controller
.controller('DetailCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicView) {
  // Show Bookmark and Hide FAQ icon
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function() {
    $rootScope.showHideFAQ = true;
    $rootScope.showHideBookmark = true;
  });

  // Hide Bookmark and Show FAQ icon
  $scope.$on('$ionicView.leave', function() {
    $rootScope.showHideFAQ = false;
    $rootScope.showHideBookmark = false;
  });
})
```